# How to clear all that's written on an HTML document?

Tags: javascript, dom

How do I clear off all that was written in a document? Is there a DOM JavaScript API that will erase all that's in the document object's buffer; an equivalent of the server-side `Response.Clear()`?

I am just practicing JavaScript.

Comment: [JavaScript DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document)

Comment: `document.write('');` would do...

Comment: What do you mean by "buffer"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the root (`html`) element using:

```
document.querySelector('html').remove();
```

or the jQuery equivalent if you have a very old browser:

```
$('html').remove();
```

Answer (score 5):

here's an alternative that doesn't require querying:

```
document.documentElement.remove();
```

Comment: Thank you, and some more characters to reach the minimum limit of characters required.

Comment: Simplest solution when starting to show JavaScript interaction with a webpage.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by “document object's buffer”? The actual visible content is usually contained in the body, so you can empty it:

```
document.body.innerHTML = null;
```

There is no buffer like in server-side preprocessor languages, because the DOM document is entirely client-side rendered.

You can even wipe all the document's descendants, clearing the `<html>` element:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('html').item(0).innerHTML = null;
```

Also, if you don't like `innerHTML`, you can also use [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent):

```
document.head.textContent = null;
```

This is because, quoting MDN:

> Setting this property on a node removes all of its children and replaces them with a single text node with the given value.

Comment: Thank you. Just what I wanted.

Comment: This only removes the body, not the head or anything outside of the body. The `<head>` tag often includes scripts and stylesheets, which are pretty significant.

Comment: @ssube: Like I said, the actual DOM elements are predominantly in the body. But likewise, you can set `document.head.innerHTML = null`.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I am aware. I've programmed JavaScript and the DOM (using both plain JavaScript and jQuery at times) but without a fundamental understanding of the JavaScript language. Now,. I am trying to study the language and the DOM properly.